# Bigquery - Error creating scheduled query: Cannot create a transfer in JURISDICTION_US when destination dataset is located in JURISDICTION_EU

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery has started throwing up this error

> "Error creating scheduled query: Cannot create a transfer in
> JURISDICTION_US when destination dataset is located in
> JURISDICTION_EU".

My datasets are all in the EU but I don't understand why it is trying to create a transfer in the US.

Has anyone had a similar issue and been able to resolve it?

Comment: You should describe what triggered the error or roughly how your setup is.

Comment: I am getting the exact same error. This happens to me when attempting to schedule a query in BigQuery. 

This process is supposed to query a table and put the results into another table (both tables under the same dataset, in location EU). Both queries and destination tables are partitioned. 

I have already scheduled some queries and those processes worked perfectly. In those cases, the queried tables were in another dataset other than the destination table (also in EU). 

Not sure where the "US" is coming from...

Comment: I believe that this was a bug from Google on their console. It worked perfectly using the bq CLI and after couple of days the error in the console disappeared (so now it works as expected in the console)

Comment: Sometimes I get an error about US location when all my data is stored in EU if I try to run a query too fast within the console. I think it defaults to US and then some progressive enhancement sets it to the actual location. I'm also getting the OP's issue in July 2021.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and did the following:

["In the UI, under More -> Query Settings, then look for Processing Location down the bottom before Advanced."](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/kbw5qn/dataset_location_problems_error_creating/)

Then I had to reload the page for it to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).